# android google+ authorization

Tags: android, oauth, google-plus, scribe

I am trying to loggin to my app via google+ on device without google play services. I use org.scribe.oauth to do this. I create `OAuthService` and call method `getRequestToken()`. As responce i see `Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: 'Consumer is not registered`.
But I register my app on developer console. What i do wrong? How should i register my app? Like Android application or I should choose `Installed->Other`item when I trying to get api key and secret.

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

To create an API key:

1. Go to the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project).
2. Create or select a project.
3. In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth.
4. In the displayed list of APIs, find the Google+ API and set its status to ON.
5. In the sidebar on the left, select Credentials.
6. Create an API key by clicking Create New Key. Select the appropriate kind of key: Server key, Browser key, Android key, or iOS key. Then click Create.

For more details, please refer [here](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth).